# Run/Execute statements only on a chosen menu option in Windows Batch script

Tags: parameters, batch-file

I have this menu in batch script:

```
ECHO *1* - A
ECHO *2* - B
ECHO *3* - C
ECHO *4* - D
ECHO *5* - runAll
ECHO *6* - Quit
```

Right now, what I do with it is if the user enter 1, then it runs the 1st one and loops back to the menu, 2 for the 2nd, etc.
If the user enters 5 then my script goes and runs 1 through 4 step by step in order.

My question is: "Is it possible to run/execute certain ones that you choose to execute?"
Let's say I want to execute 1 & 4 and loop back to the main menu. I enter "1(space)4" and the script takes those arguments/parameters and goes and finds the corresponding option and executes it. Does it make sense? Is it possible?

I do have the option of running each one of those options separately, but this idea, the one I'm talking about, makes it more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:begin
ECHO *1* - A
ECHO *2* - B
ECHO *3* - C
ECHO *4* - D
ECHO *5* - runAll
ECHO *6* - Quit

set /p CH=choose
for /f  "tokens=* delims= " %%A in ("%CH%") DO (
    if *%%A* EQU *1* call A
    ....
    if *%%A* EQU *4* call D
    if *%%A* EQU *5* call :callAll
    if *%%A* EQU *6* exit
)
goto :begin

:callAll
    call A
    ...
    call D
goto :eof
```

edit:

```
:begin
ECHO *1* - A
ECHO *2* - B
ECHO *3* - C
ECHO *4* - D
ECHO *5* - runAll
ECHO *6* - Quit

set /p CH=choose
echo nul >temp.bat
set line=title "temp script"
for /f  "tokens=* delims=;, " %%A in ("%CH%") DO (
    if *%%A* EQU *1* set line=%line% &call A 
    ....
    if *%%A* EQU *4* set line=%line% &call D 
    if *%%A* EQU *5* call :callAll
    if *%%A* EQU *6* exit
)
echo %line% >>temp.bat
call temp.bat
del /s /q /f temp.bat
goto :begin

:callAll
    line=%line% &call A 
    ...
    line=%line% &call D 
goto :eof
```

this will create (and delete after execution) a temp script which will be executed after entered options.You can create self edited script also but the code will be more hard for maintenance . the for loop process the data entered by the "customer" and executes all numbers separated by space.in "delims=" you can add commas, semicolon and what you want.

Comment: thanks! But, I have exactly the same structure in my script right now. What I wanted to do was, if it is possible, call more than one of them at once. Like, user enters 1 and hits "Enter", THEN it runs "A". That's what we have right now. However, what if the user doesn't want to run all together OR one by one? What if he/she wants to just run 1, 2 & 4, BUT does not want to have to keep entering the numbers. All he/she has to do is enter: 1, 2, 4 and the program/script should go and run only those entered by the user. Makes sense? Thanks for the input again.

Comment: there are two options 1.to use "start" instead of "call" - this will start the program/function with the corresponding letter without wait for it's finish 2.to use & which will allow to call more commands simultaneously  (eg. see the edited answer)